# Is there a limit on game updates in the iOS app store?

Tags: iphone, appstore

Does Apple implement any limit on the frequency / number of updates posted for a given app on the app store?

I have seen that apps that are updated get featured in the "new app" lists. So developers may choose to update their app every week to get featured in these lists on a regular basis?

Answer (score 5):

There is no limit, but you have to be aware that there is a delay between the moment you submit and the release du to the approval process.

New and newsworthy is a selection made by apple staff. And the rules for getting on the list and remaining there are not known/consistent.

Answer (score 5):

It is not true that your app will be listed under "New app" if you update it. Unless you release a different build with a new name for the app then your app might appear in the "New & Noteworthy" section in itunes.

Also there is no limit to the updates as the iOS version changes we have to make the existing apps compatible with the new version which requires a new update for the app.